# How to combine 3 matrices with the same number of rows but differing numbers of columns

Tags: r, matrix

I'm just trying to combine my matrices into a .txt file.  I keep getting an error message with my code:

```
dim(gcDatalmFit$coefficients)
dim(eBgcData$coefficients)
dim(eBgcData$p.value)
write.table(file="BLIMP1data.txt", cbind(gcDataGenes,gcDatalmFit$coefficients,eBgcData$coefficients,eBgcData$p.value), row.names=F, col.names=c("GeneID",colnames(gcDatalmFit$coefficients), colnames(eBgcData$p.value), paste("p",colnames(eBgcData$coefficients))), sep=",")
```

Results in:

```
[1] 45101     4
[1] 45101     6
[1] 45101     6
number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Comment: I highly recommend you make a single data object first, then save it in a separate step. That way you can look at your data and see what problems you're facing.

Comment: You did not provide a reproducible example, so it's hard to diagnose; but what is `dim(gcDataGenes)` or `length(gcDataGenes)`?

Comment: You may use the `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

Comment: Here is how I came up with gcDataGenes, it's from running eBayes on an Affy microarray then using the topTable function on it: `gcDataGenes=colnames(eBgcData)
topTable(eBgcData,coef=1,adjust.method="BY",n=10,p.value=1e-5,genelist=gcDataGenes)` which gives me a data.frame with 10 rows and 6 columns.  `dim(gcDataGenes)` came back NULL and the length was 6.

Comment: @akrun, the `cbind.fill` did allow me to create the .txt file.  But it looked awful, so I need to work out some more kinks.  Thanks!

Comment: The warning message is telling you that you are trying to `cbind` a vector of length 6 (`gcDataGenes`) with matrices with 45101 rows (your three matrices). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: are gcDatalmFit, eBgcData lists right?

Comment: @Facottons They are both MArrayLM objects

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
combine.matrix <- matrix(gcDatalmFit$coefficients, eBgcData$coefficients, eBgcData$p.value, nrow = 45101, col = 16)
colnames(combine.matrix) <- col.names=c("GeneID",colnames(gcDatalmFit$coefficients), colnames(eBgcData$p.value), paste("p",colnames(eBgcData$coefficients))), sep=",")

#then save it
write.table(file="BLIMP1data.txt", combine.matrix, row.names=F)
```